# How to change font for specific Arabbik language?

Tags: iphone

[image]

I install above fonts & fonts have added successfully in my Mac System.
I added .ttf font file in .plist for above Fonts as shown in image but font style still not appears correct.
Can any one suggest what kind of mistake I am making OR there is any other issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The font name is not the same as the font file name, you should see the correct font name in the Font Book(you can search this in Finder), and call the method with the correct font name.

[image: the font name in Font Book]

For example: 
    yourLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Capira" size:15];